# BigBlueButton - Sometimes there is a delay between the video and the voice, what can I do to prevent it from happening?

Tags: audio, video-streaming, webrtc, bigbluebutton

Hello everyone how are you, it happens that when the video call is in progress, sometimes the video is delayed with respect to the audio, and it is never re-adjusted (unless you refresh the page).

-I have ports 80 and 443 enabled
-I don't have a firewall in between
-I don't have any proxy
-The server never has more than 2 sessions and each one has no more than 12 participants

What advice or solutions can you give me in this case? Thanks in advance.